# Tree Traversal to swap two nodes

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I just came across this problem and was wondering if I could come up with a right solution. The problem involves in swapping two nodes of a binary tree not just by value but by node. So this means that we have to change the right and left values too.

[image: BST]

So lets say that we have a binary tree something like the above image. What I thought initially was to make an inorder traversal of the nodes so that I could flatten the tree and then just swap the elements and then reconstruct the tree from the swapped list. So literally the solution goes something like this

For the above mentioned tree, the inorder traversal would generate a list like this,

1,3,4,6,7,8,10,13,14.

Now I swap 8 and 13.

=> 1,3,4,6,7,13,10,8,14

But the problem here is, since I have flattened the tree now when I try to reconstruct I am not able to do so because I don't know the position of individual nodes , like whether the particular node is a left subchild or if it is a root. So literally the tree cannot be regenerated like the same as it was initially with the swapped nodes.

Now the question is whether I could modify my traversal algorithm to hold the position information of each of the nodes so that when I swap the elements and reconstruct I come up with the same binary tree with the desired nodes swapped? Can we store the state/position of individual nodes during inorder traversal?

PS. I recognize that doing a post-order would make my list with first and last nodes to be swapped but the two nodes that needs to be swapped need not necessarily be at the root and right most element, it can be any two.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ambiguities in your question. The tree in your example in BST ( though a BST is also a Binary Tree) and the final answer can break the BST property. I presume thats what the answer needs to be. Correct me if I am wrong.

As far as answer is concerned, there are 2 solutions.

One, I can think of, talking in terms of traversal and flattening, you cannot re-contruct a tree with just one traversal. You need 2 traversals to construct a tree. It could be either of the below

1. Pre order and an In order
2. Post order and an In order
3. Level order and an In order

So do the swapping on any of the 2 traversals and recontruct. That should give the answer.

The second solution is a much better and efficient solution because the Time Comp is O(n). In this method, make a traversal on the whole tree and get the reference pointers to the 2 candidate nodes. Once you have the references , use a temp variable to swap the information..This method is complex but both space and time efficient than the previous approach.

---

Hope it is not a HW question, if so please tag it !

Eg :

```
            4
        2       6
      1   3   5   7
```

The order traversal for this tree looks like this:
Pre : 4 2 1 3 6 5 7
Inorder : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

Now you know that 4 is the root of this tree (Since root gets printed as the first element for Preorder). Based on 4 now split the traversals.

Now the left sub-tree becomes 
Pre : 2 1 3 ; Inorder : 1 2 3

and the right sub-tree becomes 
Pre : 6 5 7 ; Inorder : 5 6 7

Keep doing this recursively , that will the answer !

Comment: Yes the tree that I have shown here is a BST but I did mention in the question that it is just a binary tree. So BST might be a case but it is not the only one. Regarding using both the traversals, I did thought about that but again when you do any one of the traversal for flattening and the other for reconstructing the binary tree, how is the reconstruction done again to generate the same binary tree? Can you provide an example?